# Not able to get hidden element on mousemove in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have one straight line, on that line there are dots at the end of the line, right now that dots are hidden, what i need to do if i mouse move around that dots it should have to be visible, looks like event target is not working on hidden elements, if i set as `display:block`, then i am able to get its event target, can anyone please help me how can i resolve this issue ? here i have added my code.

```js
$("#main_div_1").mousemove(function(event) {
  //console.log(event.target);
  if ($(event.target).hasClass('line-circle')) {
    //console.log('On circle');
    $(event.target).show();
  }
});
```

```css
#line_1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 218px;
  top: 211px;
  width: 317px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 0px;
}

.line-circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  //red margin-left: -3px !important;
  margin-top: -5px !important;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="center-div droppable ui-droppable">
  <div class="main_line ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1" style="position:absolute;" id="main_div_1">
    <div style="display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 218px;
  top: 211px;
  background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" class="line-circle" id="start_circle_line_1" data-line="horizontal" data-round="top" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="line line-complete" data-id="1" id="line_1"></div>
    <div style="display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 535px;
  top: 211px;
  background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" class="line-circle" id="end_circle_line_1" data-line="horizontal" data-round="bottom" data-id="1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it was `:hidden`.

Comment: please use css and not inline styles.

Comment: I cannot see them even when I remove display none

Comment: I have added css as well for circle

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: sry. but is it not curse you won't get the line-circle with event.target, when display is none?
Look at this fiddle, left side is registered curse is not display hidden, left is still the same.
https://jsfiddle.net/2jxy9avu/9/

Comment: I can only give css inline, because this is drag and drop functionality so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna leave this as a answer
https://jsfiddle.net/2jxy9avu/9/

I think is because your div has the style "display: none;"
And you need to do it another way, with background hidden,
then with js, shuffle between background color, or transparent

js

```
$(function(){

$("#main_div_1").mousemove(function( event ) {
  if($(event.target).hasClass('line-circle')  ){
    $(event.target).css("background","red");
     $(event.target).mouseout(function(){
       $(event.target).css("background","transparent");
     })
    }
  });
});
```

Html

```
<div class="center-div droppable ui-droppable">
  <div class="main_line ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1" style="position:absolute;" id="main_div_1">
    <div class="line-circle" style="background:transparent; display:block" id="start_circle_line_1" data-line="horizontal" data-round="top" data-id="1">    </div>
<div class="line line-complete" data-id="1" id="line_1"></div>
<div class="line-circle" id="end_circle_line_1" data-line="horizontal" data-round="bottom" data-id="1"></div>
```

Comment: happy i could help

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#main_div_1").mousemove(function(event) {
  $(event.target).parent('.main_line').find(".line-circle").show();  
});
```

```css
#start_circle_line_1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 218px;
  top: 211px;
  background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

#line_1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 218px;
  top: 211px;
  width: 317px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 0px;
}

#end_circle_line_1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 535px;
  top: 211px;
  background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.line-circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  //red margin-left: -3px !important;
  margin-top: -5px !important;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="center-div droppable ui-droppable">
  <div class="main_line ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1" style="position:absolute;" id="main_div_1">
    <div class="line-circle" id="start_circle_line_1" data-line="horizontal" data-round="top" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="line line-complete" data-id="1" id="line_1"></div>
    <div class="line-circle" id="end_circle_line_1" data-line="horizontal" data-round="bottom" data-id="1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In event.target you will get `<div class="line line-complete" data-id="1" id="line_1"></div>` which doesn't have a class `line-circle`.

Comment: This will not work for me, as i need to give only inline css, because this is drag and drop functionality

Comment: I didn't get it. I have not made any changes in css or html. Can you please elaborate? @TirkeshTurkesh

Comment: So you have to make a dot visible only when I hover over the dot? @TirkeshTurkesh